# Computing the average for each line of scores in a text file

Tags: python, sorting, readfile, mean

I have a set of names with 3 scores assigned to each one of them in a `.txt` file, and I want to print the average score for each name.  I have the following code so far, but I'm stuck on how to average the scores and print them in a `python` shell.

```
File_name=open('class_2.txt', 'r')
List_ = File_name.readlines()
List_.sort()
print('Class average scores below :')
for line in  List_:
    print(line)
```

This code prints the names alphabetically with the scores attached to them, but it does not print the average score.

The `.txt` file is formatted like this:

```
tom,6,4,7

steve,3,6,4

john,10,9,8

mike,6,8,9
```

Comment: Look up the `split` function, so you can get the individual numbers from the line. Then you can count the average of them and print it.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, why are you indenting after your open statement. Also, please consider opening your file with the with statement so that your file closes properly. Third, be careful with your variable names, they should be lowercase and I don't see the need to have that underscore.

Comment: Someone just downvoted my answer, but I believe it produces the correct output and is excellent code. Is something wrong with it? I can only imagine someone misunderstood what you want, so please *show the desired output* in your question. And if my answer is actually good, then please accept it. (mpolednik's answer is actually wrong, so I do understand why that gets downvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Program:

```
with open('class_2.txt') as students:
    for student in sorted(students):
        name, *scores = student.split(',')
        average = sum(map(int, scores)) / len(scores)
        print(name, average)
```

Output:

```
john 9.0
mike 7.666666666666667
steve 4.333333333333333
tom 5.666666666666667
```

Answer (score -1):

You lack the code to do the average calculation. Try the following modification:

```
with open('class_2.txt', 'r') as f:
    List_ = f.readlines()
    List_.sort()
    print('Class average scores below :')
    for line in List_:
        data = line.split(',')
        print(data[0], sum([int(score) for score in data[1:]]) / len(data) - 1)
```

This works by using the split() method to split the data into array such as ['tom', '6', '4', '7'] and then using Python's slicing to extract the values to integers, sum them and average them.

Comment: is better `len(data)-1` insteadof `3`

Comment: The indentation is still wrong here and your not explaining why your modifications work.

Comment: rather than add the `with` idea at the end, just edit your first code block to use it.